# A category where maps are factorizations - what is this called?

Tags: category-theory, terminology

Let $\mathcal C$ be a category, and define $\mathcal D$ to be the category whose objects are maps in $\mathcal C$, and where a map $f\to g$ is a factorization $pfq=g$.  Composition of $(p_1,q_1):f\to g$ and $(p_2,q_2):g\to h$ being $h=(p_2p_1)f(q_1q_2)$ and the obvious identity $f\to f$.

Does this category have a name?

For example: If $\mathcal C$ is a poset category, then $\mathcal D$ is just the closed intervals of the poset, ordered by inclusion.

$\mathcal D$ has the property that isomorphisms in the arrow category are isomorphisms in $\mathcal D$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is called the [twisted arrow category](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/twisted+arrow+category). I note with amusement that the linked definition uses exactly the same letters.

Comment: Hah, even using the word "factorization." Thanks!